# Why does MySQL tell me that the column doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have 3 tables : 
association(id,name)
race(id,name)
stats(id,date,associationId,typeId,quantity)

My goal is to have the list of all associations, and for all associations, the list of types, with the quantity, ordered by first, the total for the association, then for each type.
For this, I have this query :

```
SELECT association.name AS associationName,
        race.name AS raceName,
        SUM(report.quantity) AS quantity,
        subrequest.totalquantity as totalquantity
    FROM stats report
    JOIN association ON association.id = report.associationId
    JOIN race ON race.id = report.raceId
    JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(report.quantity) AS totalquantity,
            association.id AS subId
        FROM stats report
        JOIN association ON association.id = report.associationId
        WHERE date LIKE "2013-11-%"
        GROUP BY association.id
        ORDER BY totalquantity DESC
    ) subrequest ON subrequest.subId = association.id
    WHERE date LIKE "2013-11-%"
    GROUP BY association.id, race.id
        ORDER BY totalquantity DESC, quantity DESC
```

It is working perfectly fine ! But now, I want to have only the two biggest types for each association. I tried this :

```
set @num := 0, @association := '';
select associationName, raceName, quantity, totalquantity,
@num := if(@association = associationName, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
        @association := associationName as dummy
FROM (
    SELECT association.name AS associationName,
        race.name AS raceName,
        SUM(report.quantity) AS quantity,
        subrequest.totalquantity as totalquantity
    FROM stats report
    JOIN association ON association.id = report.associationId
    JOIN race ON race.id = report.raceId
    JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(report.quantity) AS totalquantity,
            association.id AS subId
        FROM stats report
        JOIN association ON association.id = report.associationId
        WHERE date LIKE "2013-11-%"
        GROUP BY association.id
        ORDER BY totalquantity DESC
    ) subrequest ON subrequest.subId = association.id
    WHERE date LIKE "2013-11-%"
    GROUP BY association.id, race.id
    ORDER BY totalquantity DESC, quantity DESC
) x
WHERE row_number <= 2
```

With this, I have an error : #1054 - Unknown column 'row_number' in 'where clause' If I remove the WHERE clause, it works fine and I have the results as expected. I also have a column row_number with the correct numbers.

I have to do this to make it work :

```
set @num := 0, @association := '';
select associationName, raceName, quantity, totalquantity
FROM (
    select associationName, raceName, quantity, totalquantity,
    @num := if(@association = associationName, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
            @association := associationName as dummy
    FROM (
        SELECT association.name AS associationName,
            race.name AS raceName,
            SUM(report.quantity) AS quantity,
            subrequest.totalquantity as totalquantity
        FROM association_race_report report
        JOIN association ON association.id = report.associationId
        JOIN race ON race.id = report.raceId
        JOIN (
            SELECT SUM(report.quantity) AS totalquantity,
                association.id AS subId
            FROM association_race_report report
            JOIN association ON association.id = report.associationId
            WHERE date LIKE "2013-11-%"
            GROUP BY association.id
            ORDER BY totalquantity DESC
        ) subrequest ON subrequest.subId = association.id
        WHERE date LIKE "2013-11-%"
        GROUP BY association.id, race.id
        ORDER BY totalquantity DESC, quantity DESC
    ) x
)y
WHERE row_number <= 2
```

This works fine ! But I don't understand why I need to add another level of request to make the WHERE clause to work ? It really annoys me to add an useless level of query. Is there a way to make it work ? Why does MySQL raise this error ?

Thank you !

Comment: I finally found the solution ! I just need to replace WHERE row_number <= 2 by WHERE if(@association = associationName, @num + 1, 1) <= 2

Answer (score 0):

MySQL didn't like the column reference because it gets defined in the select part of the query -- it's not available yet for use in joins and in the where clause.

The solutions, both of which I see you've found since, are to replace the alias with the expression that defines it, or to create an intermediary subquery to avoid rewriting the entire thing. (The query optimizer will nromally remove the intermediary query.)